# TCPDF - special chars like æ, ø, å

Tags: php, character-encoding, tcpdf

How can you set unicode to `ISO-8859-1` so chars like æ, ø, å will work? Now all special chars are ignored in text strings

```
new TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'ISO-8859-1', false, true);
```

Comment: yes, and it doesnt work either

Comment: just tested, works for me, may be due to what fonts you have installed or are setting for the pdf.

Comment: have testet a couple of different fonts and tried to toggle between utf-8 and iso-8859-1 and still no special chars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have your text in utf-8, use iconv first:

```
$string_iso = iconv('utf-8','iso-8859-1',$string_utf8);
```

If it's not the case, ensure that you are using proper font. I have just checked `times` and it have all special characters from iso-8859-1.

Edit:

You will also have to set `$unicode = FALSE` in `TCPDF` constructor:

```
new TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4', FALSE, 'ISO-8859-1', false, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the **solution to all the problems about writing special characters using TCPDF php script**.

Follow these steps and you will get it solved:

1. **Edit your PHP using ANSI codification**. You set it easily with Notepad++ editor.
2. TCPDF object intance creation, as usually:

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, **true, 'UTF-8'**, false);

3. When you need to write something with TCPDF methods, don´t forget enclosing the texts inside **`utf8_encode()`** php function.

This way:

```
$pdf->Cell(210, 18, utf8_encode('æ, ø, å, Camión/pícaro/rúbrica/áéíóú...  Hello world, this is Aberasturi from the Moon'),0, $ln=0, 'C', 0, '', false, false, 'T', 'C');
```

Ondo ibili!!!!

X.Aberasturi

Answer (score 0):

I've make it work using this :

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// create new PDF document

$pdf = new \TCPDF( $page_layout, 'pt', $custom_page_format, TRUE, 'UTF-8', false);

$ordinal = mb_convert_encoding( 'º', 'ISO-8859-1' );